# Split string for SMS with GSM-7 and UCS-2

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, character-encoding, sms

I wanted to figure out how I can take a string that may or may not contain unicode such as emoji and split it properly into "parts" that can be sent over SMS. I work with multiple different SMS API's and can't rely on all of them to concatenate the same (or properly), so I'd rather take the responsibility for splitting messages myself. In addition, I'm wanting to implement some sort of word-wrap so that when messages are forcibly split, I don't cut a word in half- but rather push it to the next SMS.

From my understanding, SMS is limited to 160 characters, or 153 in the case of concatenation, but that is strictly with GSM-7's 7-bit characters, and adding unicode characters in from UCS-2 makes the character limit drop significantly because of the UCS-2 encoded characters eating up more bytes. It seems that counting characters is therefore unreliable and instead I need to somehow split on bytes without ruining the message.

I'm trying to figure out how to write:

```
- get bytes of msgBody string
- get encoding type of msgBody, GSM-7 or UCS-2
- get max byte size of that encoding type
- if msgBody byte size = multiple messages, split into parts
- if first part's last character isn't whitespace, push the cut-up word's first half into the next message
- somehow insure that pushing those bytes along doesn't result in the next message being too large
```

Comment: Depending on the encoding, a character can be a different size of bytes. Not all characters are equal in size. Unless you can understand each byte and their representation, you can split by characters and look how many byte it uses, then remove a few characters and look again at the bytes.

Comment: The phone will properly concatenate fragments, so you don't need to complicate. If character is not part of gsm7 alphabet use ucs2 instead, and split fragment accordinately to maximum size of fragment. And you can always use just ucs2, cause its simpler (2bytes/char, subclass of utf16), except if you are charged for each sms/fragment.

Comment: @Marvin not all carrier can guarantee concatenation, especially cross-carrier, which is a big reason why I'm doing this. Also many of the SMS API services I'm working with don't support concatenation at all. Simply trying to determine if the entire message should be sent as UCS2 or not doesn't really fix the problem either, as even in GSM7 certain characters take up more byte-space than others (for example square brackets eat up 2 bytes where an alphanumeric character only eats up 1 byte)